# Should we have a "stratified-sampling" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[We currently have 279 questions containing "stratified sampling"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stratified+sampling), and [84 questions containing ""stratified sampling""](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22stratified+sampling%22) (the phrase, including quotation marks). Would it make sense to start tagging these with a [stratified-sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stratified-sampling) tag? I don't really feel overly qualified to do so myself...

Comment: Prima facie, this seems appropriate, but I'm not a survey expert either.

Comment: We already have tags for [sampling] and [stratification] so as long as they do not want to add more than three other tags I would have thought that was adequate.

Comment: @mdewey: I wasn't aware of [tag:stratification]. Thanks! I agree that that is all we need.

Comment: @AndreSilva: they weren't, sorry and thanks. Now they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[mdewey](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/should-we-have-a-stratified-sampling-tag?noredirect=1#comment16326_5362) points to the [stratification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stratification) tag, which is all we need.

Comment: Mark as accepted?

Comment: @amoeba: good point. (I honestly thought I couldn't accept my own answer...)